# What does "as bad as" refer to?

Tags: grammar

In Runaway Jury (2003), attorney speaks to Marlee, who asks 10 millions dollars
to swing the jury pool:

> Attorney: You know, it's amazing how easy it is to procure $10
> million. It's an interesting exercise. Ten million dollars, like it
> was nothing. But **as bad as** I want to win this case, and I do...after
> 35 years of doing this, you know... ...it's more important that I can
> rest my head on the pillow at night.

What does "as bad as" refer to? I think it must be refer to two things like:

> I like **you** as much as **my dad**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this was an exercise in formal English, the attorney might have said "As badly as I want to win this case", using the adverb "badly". The use of "bad" as an adverb is typical of informal English. This word modifies the verb "want"; the attorney badly wants to win the case.

And the meaning of "want (something) badly" is "crave", or "strongly want".

So you can understand it to mean "As strongly as I want to with this case...".

The full sentence is also idiomatic. You can use the "as...as..." structure to mean "although":

> As much as I like candy, I think cotton candy is too sweet. = Although I like candy, I think cotton candy is too sweet.

So the attorney is saying:

> Although I strongly want to win this case, and I do (want to win it), after 35 years it is more important that I am financially secure.